# Multi-cell Li-ion charging from 5V USB, without boost circuit

Tags: usb, battery-charging, lithium-ion

For various reasons I'm happy to describe in the comments section, I would like to charge large (>30S @ 1-30 Ah) Li-ion packs directly from USB. Speed is not critical and multi-day (or week) charging is not an issue. However, what is an issue is size, safety, and complexity, which are hard to come by at these cell counts (unless you have an extensive engineering department to test, test, test).

I reason that since a USB supply is 5 V (@ 500 mA - 5 A, depending on PD or not), it's conceptually easy to inject power into a 4.2 V cell. If we could split the pack up into individual cells we could connect each cell to the 5 V supply and let it soak up some charge.  No need to develop any kind of switching mode power supply or balancer.

However, in a real-world case, these cells are inseparable and so the charger has to deal with the fact that there might be 100 V or greater across the pack. Furthermore, the devil is in the details, since pragmatically it would be very dangerous (i.e. prone to user failure) to completely charge one cell before moving on to another.

I feel like the below approach should work for an arbitrary number of cells. The idea is that a microcontroller switches on both ground and positive terminals for a single cell, while switching off all other cells. A Zener diode protects against the microcontroller running amok and trying to overcharge the cells.

[image]

- The system switches at a high rate ("high" as determined by the LC filter)
- An LC smooths the current so that the battery isn't seeing a sharp PWM signal
- A Zener diode provides passive protection against the microcontroller running amok and trying to overcharge the cells
- Requires a USB power supply with good current regulation (to keep itself from blowing up)
- Not drawn are all the things required to make this work in a real-world setting, e.g. appropriate MOSFETs vs BJTs, the sensing circuit to measure input current, voltage, temperature; PWM control of the input voltage; current limiting through the Zener diode, etc...

Seems simple, does it work as easily as this? Are there some obvious pitfalls in this design?

My working assumption is that this doesn't exist in the market because most people don't want to charge a > 1 kWh, 100 V battery off of USB. If I'm wrong, please use the comment section to disabuse me of this notion.

Comment: I haven't been brave enough to explore charging lithium batteries without a dedicated controller, but one thing I notice is missing from your implementation is current limiting. Slapping 5V straight on a 4.1V zener and battery is gonna throw as much current as possible from the USB port through those - how much through each would be dependent on the diode resistance and battery internal resistance.

Comment: You're not wrong, all that is handled by the microcontroller. Drawing out the entire schematic would distract from the crucial question here, which is whether the proposal works as intended. The zener's role is to protect passively in case the uC doesn't do its job anymore.

Comment: Just a few comments. 1) limit the base current of the upper BJT as most microcontrollers cannot sink a lot of current. 2) Shouldn't the LC be flipped in order to form a LC filter? 3) Is the battery flipped? 4) What is limiting the current of zener?

Comment: Agreed. All those are intentionally left out. There is a lot of upstream glue which is required to go from a theoretical system to a real one. The transistors will likely be replaced by FETs, etc... _But does it isolate the cells the way I think it will?_ (BTW, the inductor is bracketed by two charge banks, to the left by a cap and to the right by the battery.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that transistors are not exactly switches, and they especially do not provide isolation between the sides. If you assume the top cell is "on" and its lower terminal is at ground, the lower terminal of the bottom cell is at -5V and the transistor is reverse biased. Their voltage tolerance for this situation is usually quite bad, and it will also be difficult to turn it on. Have you tried building this in Falstad and simulating it? What happens?

(The whole thing seems considerably more complicated with higher part count than just building a boost converter and balancer?)

Comment: I'm not sure it's much more complicated than a balancer, since a balancer has to have at least half the FETs shown. This system also has fewer ways to go wrong, because whereas the failure state for bad programming of the balancer's microcontroller is overcharged or undercharged cells, this depends on passives and other transistor/FET properties. I feel that's easier to idiot-proof.

Comment: That's a good comment about the reverse biasing. The scale of this gets worse with each cell. By the time I have 30S, the lowest FET/transistor is reverse biased to ~120V. If the FET/transistor cannot handle it, could I not resolve this problem by using properly rated diodes? I have not simulated it, I'd hoped to avoid a simulator until I had some reasonable confidence the idea could exist.

Comment: This also obviously depends on the microcontroller working! I'm sure turning on the wrong transistors would blow up something. It shouldn't take long to set up your schematic in Falstad.

Comment: Two years down the road, here it is simulated, but with MOSFETs: https://tinyurl.com/y2c7av2e. I need some kind of driver so that the gates stay within +-20V of Vs.

Answer (score 2):

**Part A: why this circuit doesn't work.**

Even with the transistors off, current will flow through them from the higher voltage cells to the lower voltage ones through the reverse biased junctions of the transistors, regardless of whether you use BJTs or MOSFETs. That will discharge the cells and reverse their voltage. It will also damage the transistors.

If you use BJTs, the transistors will be damaged because there is no limitation to the base current.

If you use MOSFETs, the transistors may be damaged because there is no limitation to the drain current as you charge the large capacitor.

When you turn off the transistors, the LC of the inductor and capacitor will oscillate, producing a peak of 10 V, with will damage the transistors and possibly the microcontroller.

Applying 5 V directly to a cell will blow up the USB port and damage the Li-ion cell.

EDIT: Parts B and C removed per OP's request.

**Part D: the right solution to your approach**

If you *really* must charge the cells individually from USB power, this is how to do it:

- A 5 bits to 32 outputs decoder with a disable input
- 30 transistors
- 30 each DPST relays with 5 V coils
- A 5 V - 5 V *isolated* DC-DC converter
- A CCCV 5V to 3.6 V current limiter voltage regulator.

The micro outputs a 5-bit code for the cell to be charged. The decoder turns on one and only one transistor, which turns on one and only one relay. That relay connects the output of the CCCV charger to a single cell.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I do not appreciate you projecting your battery charging style onto my question. I fully understand the risk of an unbalanced pack, and that is baked into my concept of operations. Furthermore, you have misunderstood the round-robin style of charging, which would *not* charge one battery to full state while ignoring the others. As a result, I'm currently downvoting, but am happy to change to an upvote if you remove sections B and C.